# Follow up question on Folland Prop. 2.34

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

Suppose $(X,M, \mu)$ and $(Y, N, \nu) $ are complete measures. Let $(X \times Y, L, \lambda)$ be the complete product measure.

1. If $E \in L$, do we still have $E_x \in N$ for all $x\in X$?
2. If $A \times B \in L$, do we have $A \in M$ and $B \in N$?

My thinking:

1. Yes, but I'm not sure about the reason. In the proof of Prop. 2.34 we showed that the set that a) holds is a $\sigma-$ algebra. Not sure if we can do the same in this case.
2. I'm guessing no. But I'm not sure about this.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take  the space $L$ to be the completion of Borel sigma algebra $B_{[0,1]^2}$ on $[0,1]^2$.Note that $B_{[0,1]^2}=B_{[0,1]}\times B_{[0,1]}$ and we use  $m$ the  Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$

Take a $A \subseteq [0,1]$ a non borel set.Such set $A$ exists and has Lebesgue outer measure zero.

The completion of the above sigma algebra is the sigma algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets with the Lebesgue measure $m_{[0,1]^2}$ which is the complete extension of the measure $m \times m$ on $B_{[0,1]^2}$

Then take $C=\{0\} \times A$.This set has Lebesgue outer measure zero so it belongs  to $L$,but $C_0=A$ is not in $B_{[0,1]}$

I believe,this answers both your questions